Is there a way to make TypeScript actually enforce noImplicitAny (on local variables) nowadays?
According to this answer, the error/warning reporting for variable declarations that have neither a type annotation nor an immediate initializer has been consciously removed a good while ago, because TS can to some extent infer the type by assignments made later on.
To clarify, here's a demo of TS happily allowing differing type assignments, with the inferred type at the declaration location being any:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-lbkxfg?file=src%2Fmain.ts
Here's the same code in case the link breaks:
let thing;
thing = 4;
thing = 'string';

I think allowing this is somewhat ridiculous, as preventing this kind of ambiguity / dynamic type switching is, in my eyes, one of the core reasons to use TypeScript in the first place (especially if one opts for strict mode / noImplicitAny: true in tsconfig.json). But it seems we are stuck with this "new" default behavior. But is there any way to make the TypeScript compiler or language server or ESLint (or ???) warn me about such untyped declarations today?

• I think there is almost no chance of enforcing this in TS. The existing rules in ESLint don't look like they target the exact case (I assume you're asking for requiring explicit annotations on all uninitialized variables, but not requiring them on initialized variables, right?). I'm sure someone could write their own rule but I wouldn't know how to advise on that. • Could you [edit] to say that you want to disable auto-typed variables instead of mentioning any, implicit or otherwise? Such variables are dynamic, not any, and they behave differently.

Ah, seems I've had this convo before, see above linked q/a. The answer there shows a custom eslint rule that intended to prevent this (although it looks like it just targets let, not sure if you want to target var also. I guess const is probably not an issue because it must be initialized).
